# LWC Scale Iframe when resized

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I am trying to scale the contents within the iframe when its height gets changed. Usually you can use the following but I am unsure how to do so with LWC.

Usually:

Html

```
<iframe src="..." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" />
```

JS

```
resizeIframe(obj) {
   obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

Currently what I have for LWC:

Html

```
<iframe width="800" height={height} src="..." onload={resizeIframe}> </iframe>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @api height;

    resizeIframe(event) {
        //Not sure how to access below from event.target
        //obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done something similar using flexbox, but it requires a top-down approach where you're controlling the height of the top-level container.  So this can be done in an Aura App, for instance.  Where will your component be used?